# Why BroadcastReceiver can received intent when app is closed?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

the onReceived() method is run in UI thread, but when app is closed, the UI thread should also stop, why the receiver can run? I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you put your `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest. In case you do that, it'll always be active.
If you want it to be tied to activity, then you might want to declare your receiver inside `Activity` and use `registerReceiver` / `unregisterReceiver` in `onResume` / `onPause`

Answer (score 1):

Because when you register broadcast receiver in your app, its registering in Android also. When intent is sent to your app, Android raises your app and calls callback method of receiving from your class. Its called even if your app is offline.

Comment: When android raises the app, whether it just starting the UI thread, but not start the Activity?

Answer (score 1):

A BroadcastReceiver is an App Component

As in the docs : 
*App components are the essential building blocks of an Android app. Each component is a different point through which the system can enter your app.*

And more specifically 
*A broadcast receiver is a component that responds to system-wide broadcast announcements.*

By design the BroadcastReceiver is made to answer broadcast announcement even when the App is closed.

If you don't need to respond accross application annoucement you can use the *LocalBroadcastManager* which is bound to your app proccess : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

More on the App Component : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html